# Adding a css class to knockout without breaking the default code

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to add a css class in the field.html that is used on checkout.

My code:

```
<div class="field" data-bind="visible: visible, attr: {'name': element.dataScope},
css: additionalClasses,
 css: {hideBusiness: dontShowField(element.inputName)}">
```

Now it does add the 'hideBusiness' class but the default class '_required' gets removed from the field. I'm not sure why that is?

This is the output:

```
<div class="field" data-bind="visible: visible, attr: {'name': element.dataScope}, css: additionalClasses, css: {hideBusiness: dontShowField(element.inputName)}" data-mspdevtools-ui="91cce697fb40dbd783700346b3670c29" name="shippingAddress.firstname">
~~ other code ~~
</div>
```

Without my code it outputs:

```
 <div class="field _required" data-bind="visible: visible, attr: {'name': element.dataScope}, css: additionalClasses" data-mspdevtools-ui="31d1a4eee47d38a859d9852323de30f1" name="shippingAddress.firstname">
~~ other code ~~
 </div>
```

I feel like it might have to do with the double css binding but i'm not sure how to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add your class "hideBusiness" to additionalClasses prop on the uicomponent , you can use whatever logic for this and you don't have to edit the template at all

Comment: Would you maybe be able to tell me what file exactly i would need to add it into? Is it abstract.js? I found a _setClasses function in there but i'm not sure how to access the name parameter/variable in there.

Comment: in whatever js file you have access to initialized ui component or just in component definition xml or the same xml converted to php array at runtime . Its just a observable property that you can intereact with